# Pandas if/then aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, aggregation

I've been searching SO and haven't figured this out yet. Hoping someone can aide this python newb to solving my problem.

I'm trying to figure out how to write an if/then statement in python and perform an aggregation off that if/then statement. My end goal is to say if the date = 1/7/2017 then use the value in the "fake" column. If date = all else then average the two columns together.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

np.random.seed(42)
dte=pd.date_range(start=datetime.date(2017,1,1), end= datetime.date(2017,1,15))
fake=np.random.randint(15,100, size=15)
fake2=np.random.randint(300,1000,size=15)

so_df=pd.DataFrame({'date':dte,
             'fake':fake,
             'fake2':fake2})

so_df['avg']= so_df[['fake','fake2']].mean(axis=1)
so_df.head()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have already computed the average column:

```
so_df['fake'].where(so_df['date']=='20170107', so_df['avg'])
Out: 
0     375.5
1     260.0
2     331.0
3     267.5
4     397.0
5     355.0
6      89.0
7     320.5
8     449.0
9     395.5
10    197.0
11    438.5
12    498.5
13    409.5
14    525.5
Name: fake, dtype: float64
```

If not, you can replace the column reference with the same calculation:

```
so_df['fake'].where(so_df['date']=='20170107', so_df[['fake','fake2']].mean(axis=1))
```

To check for multiple dates, you need to use the element-wise version of the or operator (which is pipe: `|`). Otherwise it will raise an error.

```
so_df['fake'].where((so_df['date']=='20170107') | (so_df['date']=='20170109'), so_df['avg'])
```

The above checks for two dates. In the case of 3 or more, you may want to use `isin` with a list:

```
so_df['fake'].where(so_df['date'].isin(['20170107', '20170109', '20170112']), so_df['avg'])
Out[42]: 
0     375.5
1     260.0
2     331.0
3     267.5
4     397.0
5     355.0
6      89.0
7     320.5
8      38.0
9     395.5
10    197.0
11     67.0
12    498.5
13    409.5
14    525.5
Name: fake, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! These are both super helpful. If I wanted to do more than 1 date ie 1/7,1/9 and 1/11 I could simply write it as

`so_df['fake'].where((so_df['date']=='20170107') or(so_df['date']=='20170105')  or (so_df['date']=='20170111'), so_df[['fake','fake2']].mean(axis=1))`

Comment: @P.Cummings Unfortunately you cannot use `or`  for pandas data structures. You need to use the elementwise overloaded version of bitwise or (`|`). I added a couple of examples to the post.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `np.where`:

```
so_df['avg'] = np.where(so_df['date'] == pd.to_datetime('2017-01-07'), 
                        so_df['fake'], so_df[['fake',
                        'fake2']].mean(1))
```

Output:

```
         date  fake  fake2    avg
0  2017-01-01    66    685  375.5
1  2017-01-02    29    491  260.0
2  2017-01-03    86    576  331.0
3  2017-01-04    75    460  267.5
4  2017-01-05    35    759  397.0
5  2017-01-06    97    613  355.0
6  2017-01-07    89    321   89.0
7  2017-01-08    89    552  320.5
8  2017-01-09    38    860  449.0
9  2017-01-10    17    774  395.5
10 2017-01-11    36    358  197.0
11 2017-01-12    67    810  438.5
12 2017-01-13    16    981  498.5
13 2017-01-14    44    775  409.5
14 2017-01-15    52    999  525.5
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do if-else in pandas is by using [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)
There are three values inside, condition, if and else

```
so_df['avg']= np.where(so_df['date'] == '2017-01-07',so_df['fake'],so_df[['fake','fake2']].mean(axis=1))

    date        fake    fake2   avg
0   2017-01-01  66      685 375.5
1   2017-01-02  29      491 260.0
2   2017-01-03  86      576 331.0
3   2017-01-04  75      460 267.5
4   2017-01-05  35      759 397.0
5   2017-01-06  97      613 355.0
6   2017-01-07  89      321 89.0
7   2017-01-08  89      552 320.5
8   2017-01-09  38      860 449.0
9   2017-01-10  17      774 395.5
10  2017-01-11  36      358 197.0
11  2017-01-12  67      810 438.5
12  2017-01-13  16      981 498.5
13  2017-01-14  44      775 409.5
14  2017-01-15  52      999 525.5
```

Answer (score 1):

we can also use [Series.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) method:

```
In [141]: so_df['avg'] = so_df['fake'] \
     ...:                   .where(so_df['date'].isin(['2017-01-07','2017-01-09']))
     ...:                   .fillna(so_df[['fake','fake2']].mean(1))
     ...:

In [142]: so_df
Out[142]:
         date  fake  fake2    avg
0  2017-01-01    66    685  375.5
1  2017-01-02    29    491  260.0
2  2017-01-03    86    576  331.0
3  2017-01-04    75    460  267.5
4  2017-01-05    35    759  397.0
5  2017-01-06    97    613  355.0
6  2017-01-07    89    321   89.0
7  2017-01-08    89    552  320.5
8  2017-01-09    38    860   38.0
9  2017-01-10    17    774  395.5
10 2017-01-11    36    358  197.0
11 2017-01-12    67    810  438.5
12 2017-01-13    16    981  498.5
13 2017-01-14    44    775  409.5
14 2017-01-15    52    999  525.5
```